# What benefits and drawbacks of OmegaCo?

Tags: simcity-2013

Since there's a lack of information on what the OmegaCo Factory actually does, I am wondering its effect, purpose, and potential drawbacks are. Is it more profitable to use OmegaCo compared to say just selling Oil/Coal/Fuel/Plastic? How does it interact with your local industry/commercial/residential?

[image: OmegaCo]

**What are the benefits and drawbacks of using the OmegaCo Factory, and how does it work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use Omega that often, however it is interesting and makes playing a little different.

**The benefits of Omega:**

- Omega Profits
- Drones for fire, police and hospital.
- Shopping Drones.
- The drones can reduce traffic and help to build a bigger city.

**The downsides:**

- Everyone in business, industry and residential is addicted to Omega and will leave if they can no longer get the fix. It in essence adds one more reason for buildings to become abandoned.
- Omega uses lots of resources. Resources are expensive, it takes a lot more time to develop Omega then it does the other resource paths, such as ore and coal to steel and alloy.
- Omega pollutes, air pollution and ground pollution is very high, and expensive to clean up.
- Omega drones leave a lot of trash, in a large city you can loose your handle on it.

Omega is not necessary or even the best way to build a city, it just makes the game more interesting, giving SC some more depth.